# alternate of join in OData Service using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, odata

I want to join two tables in LINQ, my query is some thing like

```
SELECT        mfg.MfgName
FROM            MasterProductStaging AS mps INNER JOIN
                         Mfg AS mfg ON mps.MfgID = mfg.MfgID
WHERE        (mps.MasterProductStagingID = 345345)
```

Now in LINQ, I solve this problem using two different queries

```
    var test = (from d in DataContext.MasterProductStagings
                                        where d.MasterProductStagingID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["MPSID"])
                                        select d.MfgID).FirstOrDefault();

var data = (from d in DataContext.Mfgs
                                        where d.MfgID == test.ToString()
                                        select d).FirstOrDefault();
```

The tables doesn't have any relation in `emdx` Model.
Now I to get my desired data in a single query.

Answer (score 4):

OData protocol doesn't support JOIN, but you can still retrieve related data in a single request. Here are a couple of examples from OData.org:

**http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)/$links/Products**

*Identifies the set of Products related to Category 1.
Is described by the Navigation Property named "Products" on the "Category" Entity Type in the associated service metadata document.*

**http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products(1)/$links/Category**

*Identifies the Category related to Product 1.
Is described by the Navigation Property named "Category" on the "Product" Entity Type in the associated service metadata document.*

This should give you a basic idea of OData links. And if you want to use LINQ with OData, you should first create a proxy class using WCF Data Services. Then you can LINQ queries, but bear in mind that they are more limited than Entity Framework - for example they don't have support for JOIN, but support an alternative way of retrieving related data, e.g.:

```
var ordersQuery = from o in context.Orders.Expand("Order_Details")
    where o.CustomerID == "ALFKI" 
    select o;
```

Comment: In general $expand in OData will give the same desired results as people usually want when they're doing a JOIN in a relational DB. So I wouldn't even both with the $links URLs. I would instead just write a URL like /Categories(1)$expand=Products to pull down all the data at once, like the WCF Data Services client code you wrote.