# Linq and RESTful services: how to best merge data from multiple tables in a resultset

Tags: c#, linq, rest

I'm experimenting with pulling data from multiple datasets using RESTful services.  I'm hooking up to the Cloud version of Northwind, and attempting to use Linq to get the equivalent of this:

```
SELECT TOP 20 p.ProductName, p.ProductID, s.SupplierID, s.CompanyName AS Supplier, 
    s.ContactName, s.ContactTitle, s.Phone 
FROM Products p 
JOIN Suppliers s on p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
ORDER BY ProductName
```

So, I define a class to hold my data:

```
public class ProductSuppliers
{
    public string ProductName;
    public int ProductID;
    public string SupplierName;
    public string ContactName;
    public string ContactPosition;
    public string ContactPhone;
}
```

And hook into the Northwind service:

```
NorthwindEntities dc = new NorthwindEntities (new 
    Uri("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/"));
```

After trying to set up a join, not being able to get it to work, and wandering around in the back corridors of MSDN for a while, I find that Linq joins aren't supported by the OData spec.  Which seems obvious once you think about it, given the limitations of URI syntax.

Of course, the usual thing to do is stored procs and views on the server side anyway, handling any sort of joins there.  However, I wanted to work out some sort of solution for a situation like this one, where you don't have the capability of creating stored procs or views.

My naive solution has all the elegance of medieval battlefield surgery, and it has to scale horribly.  I pulled the two tables as two separate List objects, then iterated one, used Find to locate the matching ID in the other, and Added a combined record into my Product.  Here's the code:

```
public List<ProductSuppliers> GetProductSuppliers()
{
    var result = new List<ProductSuppliers>();
    ProductSuppliers ps;

    var prods =
        (
        from p in dc.Products
        orderby p.ProductName
        select p
        ).ToList();

    var sups =
        (
        from s in dc.Suppliers
        select s
        ).ToList();

    foreach (var p in prods)
    {
        int cIndex = sups.IndexOf(sups.Find(x => x.SupplierID == p.SupplierID));
        ps = new ProductSuppliers()
        {
            ProductName = p.ProductName,
            ProductID = p.ProductID,
            SupplierName = sups[cIndex].CompanyName,
            ContactName = sups[cIndex].ContactName,
            ContactPosition = sups[cIndex].ContactTitle,
            ContactPhone = sups[cIndex].Phone
        };
        result.Add(ps);
    }

    return result;
}
```

There has to be something better than this, doesn't there?  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

**[Edit]** I've looked at the link someone gave me on the Expand method, and that works...sort of.  Here's the code change:

```
    var sups =
        (
        from s in dc.Suppliers.Expand("Products")
        select s
        ).ToList();
```

This gives me a list of Suppliers with Products for each in a sublist (dc.Suppliers[0].Products[0], etc.).  While I could get what I want from there, I'd still have to iterate the entire list to invert the values (wouldn't I?), so it doesn't look like a more scaleable solution.  Also, I can't apply Expand to the Products table to include Suppliers (Changing the from clause in prods to `from p in dc.Products.Expand("Suppliers")` results in a helpful "An Error occurred while processing this request.").  So, it doesn't look like I can expand products to include lookup values from Suppliers, since it looks like expanding is expanding parents to include children, not looking up parent values in a list of children.  Is there a way to use Expand (or is there some other mechanism besides client-side manipulation of the two tables) to include lookup values from a foreign key table?

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I'll have a look at Expand and see whether I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19267367/1119545) to a similar question. Not what you expected either, since you're required to make multiple roundtrips to the service.

If you don't control the server-side of things (or you don't want to use SPs/views/joins there) you are forced to use one of these mechanisms.

Anyway, at the very least you can improve the products-suppliers matching in your code to this:

```
var results = from p in prods
              join s in sups on s.SupplierId equals p.SupplierId 
              select new ProductSuppliers()
              {
                ProductName = p.ProductName,
                ProductID = p.ProductID,
                SupplierName = s.CompanyName,
                ContactName = s.ContactName,
                ContactPosition = s.ContactTitle,
                ContactPhone = s.Phone
              };
```

You still need to retrieve all records and join in-memory, though.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, this looks better than what I did.  Now, I tried your code directly.  First I followed the suggestion to transpose the s and the p (error was that each was out of scope on their respective side of the equals).  When I did, I got `'ConsoleApplication1.ODataNorthwindService.Product' does not contain a definition for 'SupplierId' [etc.]`.  I got the analogous for Supplier as well.  Furthermore, there is a `prods[0].SupplierID` property and it contains a value.  What gives here?